# Check whether subfolder exists in path of filename in bash

Tags: bash, github-actions, glob

I am trying to check whether a subfolder is in the path of a file and then run an action only on files in this subfolder

```
for changed_file in $changed_files; do
    echo $changed_file
    if [[ $changed_filed == *'/jsonschema/'* ]];then
        echo  $changed_file  
    else
        echo 'invalid'   
    fi
done
```

The changed files contain for ewample:

- .github/workflows/iglu-lint.yml
- .schemas/com.myapp/my_context/jsonschema/1-0-1

So it should print out the second one only but it prints 'invalid' for both.

My question what is wrong about this check? I cannot get the syntax right to match the path above.

```
if [[ $changed_filed == *'/jsonschema/'* ]];then
```

I am using this as part of a bash command on github action trying to run an action on some of the last files of the last commit.

Comment: Regex matching operator is `=~`, you are not using regex here, please do not use this tag.

Comment: `$changed_filed != $changed_file`

Comment: @mgloel : Aside from the typo in the variable name, your approach would fail if one of the file pathes contains a space. I don't know the wider context, but can't you simply do a `find . -name '*/jsonschema/*' -exec ....`?

Comment: Haha, sorry to bother you. It was a stupid typo. Thanks a ton!

Comment: How did it go? The issue is still unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array for the files in question.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

changed_files=(
  '.github/workflows/iglu-lint.yml'
  '.schemas/com.myapp/my_context/jsonschema/1-0-1'
)

for changed_file in "${changed_files[@]}"; do
  if [[ $changed_file == *'/jsonschema/'* ]];then
    echo  "$changed_file"
  else
    printf >&2 '[%s] is invalid\n' "$changed_file"
  fi
done
```

---

The regex equivalent of the test above is something like:

```
[[ $changed_file =~ /jsonschema/ ]]
```